# How to combine select and insert into sql

Tags: postgresql

I have an add request:

```
INSERT INTO LIKES_PRODUCTS AS L (L.USER_ID, L.PRODUCT_ID) VALUES('7', '1')
```

There is a request for the number of rows in the table:

```
SELECT COUNT(L.USER_ID) AS LIKES FROM LIKES_PRODUCTS AS L
```

Is it possible to combine them into a single query, so that the addition occurs first, and then only the counting of rows in the table?

Comment: How are you executing these queries? from java,php,python code etc?

Comment: Why don't you want to have two seperate statements?

Comment: You can't generally do an insert and a select in the same statement.  But...what is wrong with your current approach, and what do you have in mind?

Comment: I just do not want to make two requests. If it’s not right, I’ll leave it alone.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen: yes, you can do that

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Good answer +1, I didn't know about data modifying CTEs in Postgres.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do that with a [data modifying CTE](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/queries-with.html#QUERIES-WITH-MODIFYING)

```
with new_row as (
  insert into likes_products (user_id, product_id)
  values (7,1)
)
select count(user_id) as likes
from likes_products;
```

---

However, the final `select` does not see the effects of the previous CTE. If you always insert one row, you can simply `count(user_id) + 1` in the select. Another option is to return the inserted rows and add them to the count:

```
with new_rows as (
  insert into likes_products (user_id, product_id)
  values (7,1),(8,2)
  returning *
)
select count(user_id) + (select count(*) from new_rows) as likes
from likes_products;
```

Comment: It works well, but I noticed the problem. He first considers and then adds only. That is, if in the table of records 0, and we execute the query, we will get the result 0, although there will already be one record in the table, but we need 1

Comment: @MegaRoks: yes that's correct. The outer select doesn't see changes of the insert. You can simple add 1 to the count though: `count(*) +1`